# How to pass config variables from server (Express) to React App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am building React + Express app and I need to pass some config variables from server config into React App (for example API URL).

I need to do so in development (2 servers - Webpack Dev server + Node.js) and also in production (Only Node.js Express server with built frontend).

How to achieve this?

I tried to pass locals from Express to my template where I did `window.config = '<%- JSON.stringify(config) %>'` (EJS template system) and then used `window.config` in React App. I does not think this is right approach.

Comment: It's not super-relevant, with the caveat that un-"shielded" global vars are almost always bad. I tend to do this kind of thing via an API call when the app mounts and keep it in Redux state and connect components that need that information to a configuration slice. If you need the values before components mount then something like this is fine.

Comment: API is not good idea because it can fail very easily

Comment: ... If the API fails then your app will fail anyway (and it's why you have default values in the app). You asked, I answered, and somehow my apps just keep working.

Comment: I am taking it as one of answers :) I just hope there is better one

Comment: You can either render it (as you're doing it now) or get it from an API--what other options are there?!

Comment: Maybe there is something else :D

Comment: Like... what? Web app data is either (a) put on the page during rendering, or (b) retrieved by the page after rendering.

Comment: I understand. But there must be some common way to do the first thing. Not just by passing variables trough template. Do not tell me that for example Airbnb what is heavily React based using same method as you or me :D

Comment: ... I have some bad news for you. They're bound by the same mechanisms we are.

Answer (score 2):

React is client side and no one will suggest you to pass your server config variables like api keys to client side but if you want to pass the config variables to client side.

You can make do it as

```
// import config variable to express app.js server side
const config = require('./config.js');

// send the config variable
app.get('/getconfig', (req, res) => {
  res.json(config);
});
```

In the client side make axios get request to /getconfig in actions creator file

```
export function getConfig() {
   const req = axios.get('/getconfig')
            .then(res=> res.data)
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
   return {
        type: "GETCONFIG",
        payload: req
   }
}
```

Now you can add it to reducers switch case and then use it in any react component.

Answer (score -1):

You can consider to use [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) in webpack. This feature allow you to create global constants being used in the front-end logic. And as it is created at compile time, you can retrieve the config from Node layer.

For example, you have 2 GTM containers, one for development, another for production. And in the production webpack config, we can use some like this:

```
const config = require('./node/config/prod.js');

module.exports = {
  // skip other setting...

  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV' : JSON.stringify('production'),
      'process.env.GTM_ID' : JSON.stringify(config.gtm.id)
    });
  ]
};
```

Then in the html you can use `process.env.GTM_ID` to dynamically get the GTM id among the different environments.